# Adding custom response headers using Istio's (1.6.0) envoy lua filter

Tags: kubernetes, lua, istio, envoyproxy

I am running Istio 1.6.0.
I wanted to add some custom headers to all the outbound responses originating from my service. So I was trying to use lua [envoyfilter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) to achieve that. However, I don't see my proxy getting properly configured.

The envoy filter config that I'm trying to use is

```
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: lua-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
         inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                response_handle:logInfo(" ========= XXXXX ========== ")
                response_handle:headers():add("X-User-Header", "worked")
            end
```

I do have my ingress-gateway pods running in the `istio-system` namespace

```
❯ kgp -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-gateway-b4b5cffc9-wz75r   1/1     Running   0          3d12h
ingress-gateway-b4b5cffc9-znx9b   1/1     Running   0          28h
```

I was hoping that I would see `X-User-Header` when I curl for my service.
Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any custom headers.

I tried checking the `proxy-configs` of the ingress-gateway pod in the istio-system, and I don't see the `envoy.lua` configured at all. I'm not sure whether I'm debugging it correctly.

```
 istioctl proxy-config listener ingress-gateway-b4b5cffc9-wz75r.istio-system  -n istio-system --port 443 -o json | grep "name"
        "name": "0.0.0.0_443",
                        "name": "istio.stats",
                        "name": "envoy.tcp_proxy",
                        "name": "istio.stats",
                        "name": "envoy.tcp_proxy",
                "name": "envoy.listener.tls_inspector",
```

Please let me know what is that I'm missing or incorrectly configured.
Any advice on how to debug further also would be really helpful.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I checked on my istio cluster with version 1.6.3 and 1.6.4 your example works just fine. Take a look at below code from my cluster.

I checked it with curl

```
$ curl -s -I -X HEAD x.x.x.x/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: istio-envoy
date: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 08:35:37 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 13
last-modified: Thu, 02 Jul 2020 12:11:16 GMT
etag: "5efdcee4-d"
accept-ranges: bytes
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2
x-user-header: worked
```

**AND**

I checked it with config_dump in istio ingress-gateway pod.

I exec there with

```
kubectl exec -ti istio-ingressgateway-78db9f457d-xfhl7  -n istio-system -- /bin/bash
```

Results from config_dump

```
curl 0:15000/config_dump | grep X-User-Header
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  128k    0  128k    0     0  9162k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 9162k
               "inline_code": "function envoy_on_response(response_handle)\n    response_handle:logInfo(\" ========= XXXXX ========== \")\n    response_handle:headers():add(\"X-User-Header\", \"worked\")\nend\n"
```

So as you can see it works, header is added to request and function is active in istio ingress gateway.

---

Could you try to check it again with above curl, check istio ingress-gateway tcp_dump and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Well, I tried upgrading my Istio to 1.6.4 and still no luck.                                           `root@ingress-gateway-774c57cd45-b76c2:/# curl 0:15000/config_dump | grep X-User
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  136k    0  136k    0     0  10.2M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10.2M`

Comment: Could there be something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi @PDP, could you tell me what is your infrastructure? How did you install istio? Have you tried to uninstall istio and install fresh one or just upgraded? I´m not sure why you have 2 ingress gateway pods, as far as I know there should be just one.

Comment: Istio was freshly installed. Didn't upgrade. Just uninstalled the old one and installed 1.6.4. There are 2 ingress pods to achieve redundancy, but I also tried with just 1 and ended up with no luck.

Comment: Is your cluster on cloud or on-prem? Istio works? Can you check with bookinfo example or anything? Can you edit your ingress gateway and check if containers.args.proxyComponentLogLevel is `misc:error`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. My cluster runs in cloud and it has no issues. Bookinfo works fine and no issues. It's just that I'm not able to get the lua filter applied. Also, I confirmed that the proxyComponentLogLevel is`misc:error`. Really weird why this isn't working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Updated example filter (with warnings fixed, versions updated) as of Lua v3 and Istio v1.10.3:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: my-test-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      # context omitted so that this applies to both sidecars and gateways
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value: # lua filter specification
        name: envoy.lua
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
              response_handle:headers():add("my-oidc-endpoint", "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration")
            end
```