# Injecting credentials to the outgoing requests using envoy or istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

Let's say I'm developing some service that needs to send requests to some 3rd party endpoint. This 3rd party endpoint is secured in some way (Basic, OAuth2, or mTLS) and in my source code I don't want to bother with the security part. What would you suggest to solve that problem? Right now for the mTLS part I developed a proxy that enriches all my request with the client certificate, but still, maybe there is already a solution present in the envoy or istio?

Comment: Take a look at the sidecar with ambassador pattern. Your problem sounds a lot like that.

Comment: Thanks @vins, in general I'm aware of the pattern, my question is more in the case weather there are already some solutions using istio / envoy to just configure. I know it is possible to use istio egress to secure outgoing traffic with client certificates.

Comment: As far as I know you could do that with envoy filter. There is [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) about that. There are [few examples](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/EnvoyFilter-Samples).  There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727066/adding-custom-response-headers-using-istios-1-6-0-envoy-lua-filter/62752321#62752321) to add some custom headers to all the outbound responses.